# Nginx invalid condition "="

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm using Ngnix the following configuration :

```
upstream sync {                                                                 
    server couchbase-sync:4984;                                                 
}                                                                               

server {                                                                        
    listen 4984;                                                                
    server_name ${WEBAPP_HOST};                                                 
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';                               
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';                              
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';                                    

    location / {                                                                
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {                                       
            return 204;                                                        
        }                                                                      
        proxy_pass http://sync;                                                 
    }                                                                           
}
```

I do not want to redirect OPTIONS requests but I have a error :

`nginx_1            | 2017/01/20 09:23:40 [emerg] 9#9: invalid condition "=" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp.conf:13
nginx_1            | nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "=" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp.conf:13`

How do I solve my problem?
[Official Doc](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/#introduction)

Thank you for reading

Comment: Is this file post-processed? Maybe the `$request_method` string has become mangled. Try `nginx -T` to see what `nginx` is seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for limiting `http methods` in `nginx`:

```
limit_except GET {
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
    deny  all;
}
```

The above example will only allow everything for provided `IP Range`. And for the rest of clients only `GET method` is available.

You can use it in location blocks.

Methods available:

```
GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK, UNLOCK, or PATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case some there was some problems with characters, as Richard Smith said.
I had this problem when I was creating `nginx.conf` file at docker container. I was using `echo` command in bash, and then pasted copied text.

The problem disappeared when I created it with `nano` (pasted and saved).